# how to capture ng-repeat result after sorting but before pagination?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using ng-repeat to create a sortable, paginated table as below:

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="property in filteredProps | filter:search | customOrderBy:sortColumn:reverseSort | startFrom:pager.currentPage*pager.pageSize | limitTo:pager.pageSize as sortedProps">
```

Then I use the 'sortedProps' to provide some download functionality (downloaded result should be the same as what show up in the table). The issue is 'sortedPros' just captures the first page result not all of them and that's because of the 'limitTo' function. Does anybody know how to capture data after sorting but before pagination? I tried to put the 'as sortedProps' before 'limitTo' but didn't work.

Comment: is there any way you can short it first in the controller and then do the rest?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of 'sortedProps' I just used 'filteredProps' and call the 'customOrderBy' function to sort the content before pass it to the download function:

```
$scope.downloadTableData = function(){
        var properties = $filter('customOrderBy')($scope.filteredProps, $scope.sortColumn, $scope.reverseSort);

//the rest of the code
}
```